# OpenId Connect not working on ios 7/8 (OpenID Connect/React)

Tags: javascript, ios, openid-connect

I have the OIDC implemented in my React Project. When I start my application in ios 7/8, I get a blank screen.
In other higher versions it's working fine.

I'm calling an init() function in my index.tsx:

```
    /**
     * Initialize Auth module.
     * @param {Object} config Configuration options.
     * @returns {Promise<User>} A promise with the user data.
     */
    init(config) {

        /* main configuration */
        .
        .
        .
        .

        
        return _run()         // Removing this function call makes the app work fine on iOS 7/8
            .then(() => {
                return _user;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return _user;
            });
    }
```

This _run() function is defined as:

```
function _run() {
    return _mgr
        .signinRedirectCallback()
        .then(user => {
            // if this is a signin redirect action then set the user info
            Logger.info('signinRedirectCallback: Successful redirect signin.', user);
            return (_user = user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // otherwise this is a page reload
            Logger.info('signinRedirectCallback: Page reload.', error);

            // Execute logic to check if the user is still authenticated, it invokes a silent signin call which happens through an iFrame.
            return _mgr
                .signinSilent({ redirect_uri: _config.oidc.silent_redirect_uri })
                .then(user => {
                    // if user is still authenticated then set the user info
                    Logger.info('signinSilent:  Page reload. Successful silent signin.', user);
                    return (_user = user);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // otherwise unset user info
                    Logger.info('signinSilent: Page reload.', error);
                    _user = null;
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                });
        })
}
```

**If I remove the _run() function call from my init() function, the app starts working fine on iOS 7/8**.

What's causing this issue and how can I make it work for iOS 7/8?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue after going through some documentations.

OIDC library uses babel-polyfill to add support to the old web browsers.

Reference- [OIDC Documentation](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)

According to the polyfill documentation, the minimum supported version for iOS is 9.

Reference- [Minimum supported version for polyfill](https://polyfill.io/v3/supported-browsers/)

This is why the app is running perfectly on iOS 9 and above and shows a blank screen on iOS 7 and iOS 8.